# TSLint no shadowed variable, where do I turn this off?

Tags: visual-studio-code, tslint

I've looked in the documentation, on stack, exhausted gooogle. I've read multiple instances of people being told to just 'turn this off' but no real way on how to do it.

No variable of "tslint.noShadowedVariable" configuration that I add to VSCODE settings file works.

I'm using redux in my angular app and it keeps saying that the action and state objects are 'shadowed' in every variable. At this point it works as intended and I just want to turn that warning off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable [`noShadowedVariable`](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-shadowed-variable/) in your [`tslint.json`](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/configuration/) configuration file:

```
"rules": {
     "no-shadowed-variable": false
}
```

Comment: thanks, just found it there -- it waas actually `"no-shadowed-variable": false,` and it already existed there, set as 'true' ended up switching it to 'false' thanks.